# gtk+-3.0 not found issue

Tags: gtk, vala, deb, launchpad

I'm writing program using Vala language. When I try to build a `.deb` package on Launchpad, I get this error[image: error]

CMake can't find `valac` package `gtk+-3.0`. It uses `valac` version `0.30`. Though it does find it, when I do this on my computer (use cmake to build).

This is first time I try to build `.deb` package, so I'm a bit confused with what to do... Can anyone tell me how to fix this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error is quite clear, CMake can't find the [`pkg-config` package](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pkg-config) named 'gtk+-3.0'.

You have to install the [Ubuntu package containing the `gtk+-3.0.pc` file](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=gtk%2B-3.0.pc&mode=exactfilename&suite=xenial&arch=any) (which is `libgtk-3-dev`) in order to compile and link against the libgtk+-3.0 library.

In fact `pkg-config` is available in many Linux distributions and it always looks for the `gtk+-3.0.pc` file in it's search path. The package containing this file (and the development headers and libraries) may be named differently on differnt Linux distros.

While we are talking about Vala: The valac compiler also has a command line switch named `--pkg` (e.g. `--pkg gee-0.8 --pkg gtk+-3.0`) which uses the `pkg-config` to determine the necessary headers and libs to build against libraries that come with a `.pc` file.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This helped!